# Free or commercial code analysis service for Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, code-analysis

Anyone know a good code analysis service or tool for vb.net? Like the one for c# with visual studio 2008 team edition or style cop for c#

Update:
My bad ,I am only using the visual studio pro in my new work place,so I could not use the code analysis for visual studio 2008 team edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that Code Analysis works on VB.NET code as well.

---

I just tested it, and it does work.

Comment: To expand on this, Code Analysis works on compiled assemblies, so should be language-agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

[FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Besides, you can use

NDepend http://www.ndepend.com

Gendarme from Mono. http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/gendarme/

ReSharper http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/